# what is the scope of "this" in coffeescript classes

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript

I'm still confused by scope and the context of "this" in coffee script and javascript inheritance.   Why is this(@) used for creating static methods as well as referencing instance methods, like the difference between  @myStaticMethod and @move, what is "this" representing in both cases?

e.g.

```
class Animal

    @myStaticMethod : () ->
            console.log this is a static method
    move:(numberOfLegs) ->
        console.log numberOfLegs + ' legs moving'

    run: (numberOfLegs) ->
        @move(numberOfLegs)

class Dog extends Animal

    sprint: () ->
        return @run(4)

dog = new Dog()
dog.sprint()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `@run()` because `run()` is the local function call.

```
class Dog extends Animal

sprint: () ->
    run = (x) ->
        alert x

    run(4)
```

From the other hand `@run()` is a `this.run()` JavaScript analog. As you use inheritance in you example then method `run` is extended to `Dog` from `Animal` and as a result moved to `Dog`'s prototype. So you should call `run` from current object.

> Why is this(@) used for creating static methods as well as referencing
>   instance methods

`@` signs are different in these 2 cases. In your example if you want to call static method you should write `Animal.myStaticMethod()` both inside and outside class. But when you need to call instance method inside class you use `@` just like equivalent of `this` in JS.

Look at small example in [CoffeeScript console](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Animal%0A%20%20%40staticMethod%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20instanceMethod%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20method%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20static%20call%0A%20%20%20%20Animal.staticMethod%28%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20instance%20method%20call%0A%20%20%20%20%40nonStaticMethod%28%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20local%20function%20call%0A%20%20%20%20local%20%3D%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%201%0A%0A%20%20%20%20local%28%29). As you can see on the right side `staticMethod` is not added to prototype so it is not instance method and `@` in this case has nothing common with `@` in `@instanceMethod()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, just edited the question to focus more on the question of the context of "this"